# How to add a custom plugin to chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm having a hard time creating my first plugin for chart.js
After watching a few tutorials, I made the code below expecting to get "chart" in the console but nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.1.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@2.1.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const tooltipNote = {
      id: 'tooltipNote',
      beforeDraw: chart => {
        console.log('chart');
      }
    }

    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      responsive: true,
      data: {
        labels: ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
        datasets: [{
          data: [42, 119, 53, 55, 62, 53],
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            offset: true
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          tooltipNote: {
          },
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never register your plugin as documented here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html

You can either only register it specific chart instances like so:

```js
const tooltipNote = {
  id: 'tooltipNote',
  beforeDraw: chart => {
    console.log('chart');
  }
};

new Chart(ctx, {
  data: data,
  options: options,
  plugins: [tooltip note]
});
```

Or you can register it globally so it is available to all your instances:

```js
const tooltipNote = {
  id: 'tooltipNote',
  beforeDraw: chart => {
    console.log('chart');
  }
}

Chart.register(tooltipNote);
```

What you did was only define the options as an empty object for your plugin.